# Viewmode changes from orthographic after using mousewheel. Blender 2.8 (Release candidate 3)

Tags: 3d-view, orthographic

If I change to side ortho views, when I move the angle of my view with the mouse wheel, as to rotate my view around the object, it goes back to prespective view, even if I had user ortho enabled beforehand.

I can't seem to find any settings to change this nor anyone else with this issue, but if you can any links will be helpful.

Comment: Can confirm this behavior, not sure if that was intended by the developers.

Comment: It's an odd behavior choice then. In a previous beta however this was not the case, it worked just like 2.79 worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting is to automatically go back to perspective. To dissable this, uncheck the Auto Perspective checkbox in the Preferences/Navigation.

[image]

Comment: You're right. Here is a ticket were the devs explained this https://developer.blender.org/T67815

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why they have this option enabled by default.

Comment: @sacrish not sure. Back in 2014 they had decided to have it off by default, can't find a ticket where they discussed changing the default. Might have been a meeting and not on the bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you very much!